# How to create custom Gmail labels?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I want to create custom labels for Gmail which would sit right on top of the inbox. What is the best way to accomplish this, Greasemonkey scripts or Google gadgets?

Comment: Not sure if you can do this with Google Gadgets.

Comment: Google Gadgets are long gone.

Answer (score 2):

On the left hand side of Gmail, below the `Compose` button, you will find the option to `Create new label`.

Comment: I want to create custom labels not use the existing ones.

Comment: The option is hidden under the _more_ button as shown [here](http://ompldr.org/vZnZ1ZQ)

Answer (score 1):

The create new labels:

1. Select the Gear on the right side of the page
2. Select Settings
3. click the "Label" tab
4. The labels page is divided into sections: system labels, circles, Labels.
5. In the labels section is a "Create New label" button.

Any of the labels can be made to appear on the left side of gmail. Using the show/hide option. This make is easy to pick the label when you want to see all the messages with that label.

Any label can be used as the basis of a "multiple-inbox"